get analytics details for WhatsApp Business using the Cloud API
I'm trying to make a GET request to the Facebook Graph API to fetch analytics for a WhatsApp Business Account using Postman. The request is structured as follows:
https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/{whatsapp-business-account-ID}?fields=analytics.start(1732672800).end(1732932000).granularity(DAY)&access_token={access-token}

What I've Tried:
Set the request type to GET.
Added all the required query parameters (fields, start_time, end_time, granularity, access_token) in Postman.
Checked that the access_token is valid with the right permissions (whatsapp_business_management).
Problem:
When I send the request, I get an error response:
json
Copy code
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (analytics) on node type (WhatsAppBusinessPhoneNumber)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}

What I Need:
Clarification on whether analytics is a valid field for a WhatsApp Business Account.
How to set up this request correctly in Postman or any potential troubleshooting steps.
Any additional permissions or API version considerations to make this work.
Additional Details:
Access token: Valid and has whatsapp_business_management permission.
API version: v21.0 (can switch to another version if necessary).
End goal: Retrieve analytics for a specific date range with daily granularity.

"Clarification on whether analytics is a valid field for a WhatsApp Business Account." - yes, it is - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/analytics However you appear to not be using a WABA ID here, but a phone number instead - those are different entities.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account: "To find the ID of a WhatsApp Business Account, go to Business Manager > Business Settings > Accounts > WhatsApp Business Accounts. Find the account you want to use and click on it. A panel opens, with information about the account, including the ID."
